# div onclick without full page reload?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, onclick, updatepanel

i am using < div onclick="""> to call the server side .How can i avoid full page refresh when user click the < div>?

Here is my coding.

HTML

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">  <ContentTemplate>
 <div id ="cde" runat="server" style="background-color: #00FFFF" > </div>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"> </asp:Label>
 </ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server side

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //--Register for div onclick function --
        cde.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "divMember_Click");
        //**Register for div onclick function**
    }
protected void divMember_Click()
    {

        this.Label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();

    }
    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))
        {

            if (eventArgument == "divMember_Click")
            {

                divMember_Click();

            }

        }
    }
```

I try putting the label within the update panel . But postback will still occur. How can i refresh the label without full page reload?

Comment: Do you have a ScriptManager element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Jquery .ajax function or pagemethod.YourWebMethod.

Create Web Method in your C# Code and call it using these two functions.

You can do Page Method by EnabledPageMethod="true" in script Manager and use Jquery .ajax function put jquery java script.

This will be on page behind code (create Web Method):

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{

  [WebMethod]

  public static string GetDate()



{
```

return DateTime.Now.ToString();

```
}

}
```

As referenced in Default.aspx, this is java script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
});

    <head>
  <title>Calling a page method with jQuery</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the div and Label into UpdatePanel

Comment: Hi , i try adi.i have put the label and div inside the updatePanel , but postback will still occur :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

Keep your label in the Update Panel id"Updatepanel1" with following properties

```
Update Mode : Conditional
EnableViewState : true(if you are using it)
```

Comment: u means the udatePanel control properties? i try set the update mode to conditional. but still the same :(

Comment: In order to partially load the page, use multiple update panel in the page.

Comment: i try use multiple update panal in the page. but it still will postback ,mayb u provide me a sample?

Comment: Have your enabled partial rendering in the script manager? If not use define EnablePartialRendering="true" in the script manager properties.

Comment: Let us say you have two update panel like up1 and up2. You have placed the label in the up1 and the other form or button placed in the up2. Now on the click event in the up2, label placed in the up1 should be updated without loading the full page. Set the following stuffs 1. Set EnableParitialRendering ='True'(Script Manager) 2. Set Update Mode :Conditional(up1) 3. Set Update Mode : Always (up2). All set up done here. On click of a button in the up2, do your work and call up1.Update(); That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an asp:ScriptManager present on your page to use UpdatePanel.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx).